# Why are images distorted after compressing image streams in PDF manually?

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext, distortion

I am creating an application which converts Images to PDFs. It also has a feature which compresses the already created PDFs. Both features are working. But the problem occurs in case of compression, I.e. PDF file compressed successfully, but most of the images in compressed PDF file are distorted. I am Using Itext.pdf library for conversion. I am pasting both pictures,
The first image is from the compressed PDF and the second one is from the Compressed PDF
[image: Image in normal PDF]

[image: Image in Compressed PDF]

I am pasting my code also

```
// Code for the button, which user Presses to compress a PDF File, I just have chosen a static 
  file for testing here.

   btnCompressPdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              try {
                  File mfile;
                  mfile = getFilesDir();
                  farray = mfile.listFiles();
                  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(farray[0]));
                  compressReader(reader);
                  saveReader(reader);
                  reader.close();
              }
              catch(FileNotFoundException ex){

              } catch (DocumentException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }

      });
```

Below is the code for  functions which I have used in above Button code

```
private void compressReader(PdfReader reader) throws IOException {
    int n = reader.getXrefSize();
    PdfObject object;
    PRStream stream;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        object = reader.getPdfObject(i);
        if (object == null || !object.isStream())
            continue;
        stream = (PRStream) object;
        compressStream(stream);
    }

    // code of 'compressStream' function which is called in above function i-e compressReader

   private void compressStream(PRStream stream) throws IOException {
    PdfObject pdfSubType = stream.get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);
    System.out.println(stream.type());
    if (pdfSubType != null && pdfSubType.toString().equals(PdfName.IMAGE.toString())) {
        PdfImageObject image = new PdfImageObject(stream);
        byte[] imageBytes = image.getImageAsBytes();
        Bitmap bmp;

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        if (bmp == null) return;

        int width = bmp.getWidth();
        int height = bmp.getHeight();

        Bitmap outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas outCanvas = new Canvas(outBitmap);
        outCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0f, 0f, null);

        ByteArrayOutputStream imgBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        outBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, imgBytes);


        stream.clear();
        stream.setData(imgBytes.toByteArray(), false, PRStream.BEST_COMPRESSION);
        stream.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.XOBJECT);
        stream.put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.IMAGE);
        stream.put(PdfName.FILTER, PdfName.DCTDECODE);
        stream.put(PdfName.WIDTH, new PdfNumber(width));
        stream.put(PdfName.HEIGHT, new PdfNumber(height));
        stream.put(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT, new PdfNumber(8));
        stream.put(PdfName.COLORSPACE, PdfName.DEVICERGB);
    }
}
 
  // code for saveReader Function
    
  private void saveReader(PdfReader reader) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"inside saveReader",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("myFileCompressed"+".pdf", 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fileOutputStream);
    stamper.setFullCompression();
    stamper.close();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Pdf Created Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: If you compress a pdf file then you should first decompress before use. What you do first after decompressing is checking if file sizes of original and decompressed one are the same.

Comment: Yes After decompressing, the size of decompressed file is smaller than original file.
I am opening all the pdf files in my PDFViewer which I created in my app. The images, I have pasted in this post are from PDFViewer , one from original pdf file and second from compressed PDF file. Can you guide me how to decompress a pdf file before opening it in PDF viewer.

Comment: It does not matter if it is a pdf file or another type of file. If you compress a file and then decompress the compressed one you should get the original file back. So please use code that has nothing to do with pdf, pdfreaders and pdf viewers. Are you compressing to zip?

Comment: In My app user selects a pdf file from list and open it in PDFViewer. So How can I know that the selected pdf file is Compressed or not? and After that how can I decompress that file programmatically

Comment: I am not compressing to zip. I am only reducing the file size of PDf file.

Comment: It looks like you make the assumption that the source PDF Image is in RGB format. I would check/log what the source PDF color space is.